# SQLITE select from where help (PHP)

Tags: php, sqlite

I need some help here.

Here the code:
if $s = a number my code works but the second I add a letter in there it doesnt work.
because sometimes $sel = T10
and sometimes $s = 9 with no letter

```
$results = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM i
WHERE n  = '".$s ."';");
echo "IP:  ";
while($table = $results->fetchArray()){
echo "6.";
echo "<td> ".$ta['i']."</td>";
}
```

If I do a direct sql query in my DB manager app.

```
SELECT id FROM ip
WHERE cbn  = 'c5'
```

this works with letter...number...but I need this to work in my php page.

any help please.

Comment: strings need quotes, integers don't

Comment: how you suggest I do this ? WHERE cbn  = '".$sel"); like tis ?

Answer (score 0):

for string you  should use

```
$results = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM ip
  WHERE cbn  = '".$sel ."';");
```

while for integers (numbers)

```
$results = $handle->query("SELECT * FROM ip
  WHERE cbn  = ".$sel .";");
```

Comment: It gives no error now, but it doesnt find anything. it prints nothing on my page, but its there in my db.

Comment: be sure for proper quotes  sequence .. eventually .. update you question and show the exact code you are using ..

Comment: updated. with current update, it doesnt print anything on my page. it actually works only for numbers still. but no letters.

Comment: If you don't have error.. and no result this mean that the query is formally correct but your $sel don't match any value for cbn column

Comment: but that makes no sense because its here, I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

What SQLite database are you using. There is an issue with your while loop. If you are using SQLite3, the while statement should be

```
While ($tabel = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
//code goes here
}
```

This should work if it's SQLite3 you are using.